# User Profile access issue

Tags: user-profile, user-profile-service

I have to access a User Profile application for user profile manipulation by PowerShell.

Environment:

I have two user profile service applications installed in my farm.

I wrote this code:

```
$site = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite("http://XXXXXX/_layouts/15/ManageUserProfileServiceApplication.aspx?&ApplicationID=XXXXXXX   GUID   XXXXXXXXXX); 
$ServiceContext = [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPServiceContext]::GetContext($site); 
$ProfileManager = new-object Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileManager($ServiceContext)
```

The problem is that this code always points to the same (the first created) User Profile Service application.

I changed the GUID to point to the second User Profile application but it still points to the firts one. How can I reach the second one?

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I am really struggling on it. I am already using the service context but it always point to the first created user profile. Actually I am setting-up two user profile one on windows authentication and other one with claim base authentication. when I get UserProfileManager from serviced Context it always point to first created profile. the link you provided is also do the same.

Answer (score 0):

I worked more and figure-out the problem myself.

if we are creating two user profile application services within the same farm, we have to create a different proxy group in order then it wont point to the same user profile.

Creation of Separate Group
Application Management -> Configure Service application association.

Thanks